# Adding WHERE clause if record exists

Tags: mysql, left-join, exists

I'm working on a query wherein I have three tables to join, however the third table may or may not have a relevant record.

I currently have:

```
  SELECT table1.val, table2.val, table.3.val 
  FROM
      table1
      LEFT JOIN table2
          ON table1.val = table2.val
      LEFT JOIN table3 
          ON table.3.val = table2.val
  WHERE
      table1.name = "name" 
      AND table3.name = 'certain name'
  ORDER BY table1.val ASC
```

How can I write this so that if `'certain name'` doesn't exist in `table3`, that portion is omitted from the `WHERE` and `SELECT` clauses? I'm actually selecting several more fields but this should adequately demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that result form `table3` should only be visible, if the `table3.val` is equal to the `table2.val` AND that the `table3.name` should equal `'certain name'`, then this will fit you:

```
SELECT table1.val, table2.val, table.3.val 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.val = table2.val
LEFT JOIN table3 
ON table.3.val = table2.val AND table3.name = 'certain name'
WHERE table1.name = "name" 
ORDER BY table1.val ASC
```

After all, this is what `LEFT JOIN` is for...

Comment: ha! It's just that easy, eh? Not sure why moving from the where to the on hadn't occurred to me. This solved my issue, thanks pp!